# CSS: Element fixed to viewport height, scaled proportionally, centered

Tags: css

I have elements which have a set height of 100% viewport height. Inside of these are a background image which is also fixed to the same height - so the image's top and bottom are always visible, it's centered, and sometimes it's edges get cut off.

What I'm trying to add on top of this is another element which matches the same behavior of the background image (to place other things over the image, but ensure they always line up).

I have a working example using Javascript, but wondering if this same behavior could be replicated with CSS. The pinkish box is the element which I am scaling based on the viewport's size and it should always match up with the background image behind it.

https://jsfiddle.net/louiswalch/p1rkohzt/

And all the scaling logic is as follows:

```
var $window             = $(window);
var base_width          = 1600;
var base_height         = 960;
var base_ratio          = (base_width / base_height);
var contents            = $('SECTION .content');

$window.on('resize', function() {

  var window_width    = $window.width();
  var window_height   = $window.height();
  var window_ratio    = (window_height / window_height);

    var scaled_width    = (window_height * 100/base_height) * base_width/100;

  contents.css({
      width: (scaled_width+'px'), 
    height: (window_height+'px'), 
    marginLeft: ('-'+scaled_width/2+'px'), 
  });

}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Sounds very similar to `background-size: cover` and multiple backgrounds

Comment: Not sure how to display it better and not even sure if understand it properly, but take a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/FlyingDR/pen/qVPzPz), here is your markup and each item stretches to viewport.

Comment: The contents of the box will not be images, they will be other elements positioned to scale with the background. Getting the .content element to match the image (even if the image is being cropped on the sides) is key to ensuring that elements and background image will align.

Comment: I see. In this case there is no CSS solution, I'm aware of because background image provides no information about its size. You can, however, use image not as background, but explicitly within your container element so it will provide its size (or aspect ratio) to container and then use `position: absolute` for other elements to let them to be positioned within container. You may need to provide more precise example of your particular case to be able to get better answer.